# How to use a Linux bash function to "trigger two processes in parallel"

Tags: linux, bash

Please kindly consider the following sample code snippet:

```
function cogstart
{
    nohup /home/michael/..../cogconfig.sh
    nohup /home/michael/..../freshness_watch.sh
    watch -n 15 -d 'tail -n 1 /home/michael/nohup.out'
}
```

Basically the freshness_watch.sh and the last watch commands are supposed to be executed in parallel, i.e., the watch command doesn't have to wait till its prequel to finish. I am trying to work out a way like using xterm but since the freshness_watch.sh is a script that would last 15 minutes at the most(due to my bad way of writing a file monitoring script in Linux), I definitely want to trigger the last watch command while this script is still executing...

Any thoughts? Maybe in two separate/independent terminals?

Many thanks in advance for any hint/help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As schemathings indicates indirectly, you probably want to append the '&' character to the end of the line with freshness_watch.sh.  (without the single-quotes). I don't see any reason to use '&' for your final watch command, unless you add more commands after that.

'&' at the end of a unix command-line indicates 'run in the back-ground'.

You might want to insert a sleep ${someNumOfSecs} after your call to freshness_watch, to give it some time to have the CPU to it's self.

Seeing as you mention xterm, do you know about the crontab facility that allows you to schedule a job to run anytime you want, and is done without the user having to login? (Maybe this will help with your issue). I like setting jobs to run in crontab, because then you can capture any trace information you care to capture AND any possible output from stderr into a log/trace file.

Answer (score 2):

```
( nohup wc -l *  || nohup ls -l * ) &   
( nohup wc -l *  ;  nohup ls -l * ) &
```

I'm not clear on what you're attempting to do - the question seems self contradictory.